# Python and mongodb select

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have the following documents in mongodb:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50bc8c38cb5ecd32fb8d12d3"} , "p" : 0 , "d" : <Binary Data> , "kid" : 6384}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "s6bc8c3phg5ecd32bbgd12f3"} , "p" : 1 , "d" : <Binary Data> , "kid" : 6384}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "k7bc8kf8vg5echy2bbgd12m5"} , "p" : 1 , "d" : <Binary Data> , "kid" : 6385}
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "k7bc8kf8vg5echy2bbgd12m5"} , "p" : 1 , "d" : <Binary Data> , "kid" : 6386}
```

I would like to query the db to give back only the ones that have the same kid but different p. For each kid it should return 2 rows if exists otherwise none.

In example the result should be:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50bc8c38cb5ecd32fb8d12d3"} , "p" : 0 , "d" : <Binary Data> , "kid" : 6384}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "s6bc8c3phg5ecd32bbgd12f3"} , "p" : 1 , "d" : <Binary Data> , "kid" : 6384}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: No, you can't do that in a query.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do two queries or sort them clientside.

Answer (score 0):

You could use as one of your two queries the aggregate method

```
db.myTable.aggregate( [ { '$group': { '_id': "$kid", 'count': { '$sum': 1 } } }, 
                        { '$match': { 'count': { '$gt': 1 } } } ] )['result']
```

which should give you a list of the kids with more than one parent

```
[{u'count': 2, u'_id': 6384}]
```

Then, you could do a find for those kids.